# how to add custom select field in magento admin near Reset Filter button

Tags: magento

is it possible to add custom select field in magento admin near Reset Filter button? i want to place a select field near reset filter button for processing  back-end  process with filters from custom select box. any help would be great!

Answer (score 5):

Really old question but still... maybe is useful to someone

In your **Grid.php** you could override public function getMainButtonsHtml() from Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid

I have use this to add a custom button next to admin grid filter buttons, but you can insert any html / block output

```
public function getMainButtonsHtml() {
    $html = parent::getMainButtonsHtml();
    $add_artwork_button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
        ->setData(array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Add artwork to contract'),
            'onclick'   => 'javascript:openArtworks();',
            'class'   => 'save'
        ));
    $html .= $add_artwork_button->toHtml();
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to add a custom column to a Magento admin grid. If so please see this post: [Add a dropdown attribute in Product report grid Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384677/add-a-dropdown-attribute-in-product-report-grid-magento)